How do i resolve this issue with no display signal after finishing installation process?
It installed ubuntu just fine and it was working. I pressed reboot like it said to do so it can finish the installation process an boot from internal storage. Get to the point it tells me to remove the installation medium (USB) then press enter that's exactly what I did.
It was supposed to boot back up through internal storage. It turned on but never gave me signal on my tv. I have tried all the available ports that send display signals. I have 2 displayports and 1 vga port.
My tv says on signal. The desktop (Lenovo ThinkCentre m920s) is on. I've tried multiple ports on my tv. I've also tried other tv's.
Please if you could help I'd really appreciate it! I'm new to all this an really don't want my experience to be ruined by possible user error.
I'm very new to having a PC. I just got it and it needed a OS. So I choose ubuntu because I wanted a minecraft server plus something without bloat like windows.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't even get into bios because I can't see the video output on my screen. So I'm kinda stuck at this point.
THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP!! ID REALLY APPRECIATE IT PLEASE!!! 

Can you still boot from the installation USB? (Without actually installing, of course). Then you might find the syslog or boot log on the hard drive that tells you what went wrong.

I couldn't get it to boot with the USB or show that it has signal on any of the ports. I pressed f1 repeatedly hoping to get bios as well but no return of video signal.

The default configuration for a Lenovo ThinkCentre m920s appears to use a
Integrated Intel UHD Graphics 630 video card which has known issues with linux for certain kernel versions.
First, you should try the procedures in this answer to try to recover video and try alternate video drivers.  Especially try ubuntu-drivers autoinstall which may automatically select the correct driver for you.
Other directions in that answer may also solve this problem.
If none of those automatic solutions work
and you are using the default video configuration for this system, and you are running kernel version 4.10 - 5.10, then get to the grub screen as in that answer and edit the live boot entry and replace or insert before quiet the option i915.alpha_support=1.   The automated options may provide a better solution, but if those don't work and this does, then you can make it permanent by editing /etc/default/grub and edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line and add the option there and then run update-grub.

I can't see anything though. How would I be able to put that into the terminal?

I get no display at all out of any of my displayports or my vga port but the PC lights are on indicating that it's on.

If you can get a shell on the machine via remote connection or terminal, this is all a lot easier.  Otherwise you have to interrupt grub and get the grub menu.

I have no idea what grub even is. I can't get into a terminal if i have zero visual confirmation. My tv screen say no signal. How would I be able to pull up a grub menu when its has nothing coming on the screen. No signal at all.

Have you read the other answer I linked?  It covers all of this.

I did an tried to follow some of the instructions I sat there for 10 mins mashing esc lolthat's didn't work. It's not a black screen it's a no signal screen.

shoudln't take 10 minutes...sounds like you didn't hit it soon enough or maybe often enough.  Presumably you are seeing a bios POST screen at power up?  Once that clears, if you don't get a menu or the grub prompt within a few seconds, it's too late and you missed it.

Im not getting nothing to come on screen when it posts at all though like I'm saying i don't have anything coming on screen it's like there is nit device connected to my tv. Just says no signal

The reason why I said 10 mins is because o tried it repeatedly lol

It is certainly a timing issue...have ti press esc at just the exactly right time, and it's less than 2 second window.  That's why I recommend pressing it repeatedly.

Lol that's what I did. That's what mashing the esc button means

How would i miss the less than 2 second window If im repeatedly hitting the esc button from the moment I press the power button.
